# making q.r. reader with zxing without installing external app using Android studio

Tags: android, zxing

Yes there are plenty of answers of this question on this site, but i am a newbie and having difficulties managing eclipse code examples in android studio. Suggest answers by considering me a beginner please(step by step). So many links, which to open? which projects library to embed? and which java files to be used in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this awesome open source project:
https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView
It's easy to implement and you only need to add a dependency in your **module's** build.gradle (not the project one)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'

}
```

the rest is intuitive:

- You use an element in your layout witch will be the QRCodeReaderView (take a look at the project's layout file)
- You will need to add the permission to the manifest file

  ```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.myawesomeapp">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


  <application
      ...
  </application>
  ```

Let me know if you have any questions